# Flask - How can I use my functions on the URL

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm starting to learn Flask and maybe I'm just using the wrong words to search, but here's the problem.

I have this class:

```
class Video(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def get(self, video_id):
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=video_id).first()
        if not result:
            abort(404, message="Could not find video with that id")
        return result

    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def put(self, video_id):
        args = video_put_args.parse_args()
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=video_id).first()
        if result:
            abort(409, message="Video id taken...")

        video = VideoModel(id=video_id, name=args['name'], views=args['views'], likes=args['likes'])
        db.session.add(video)
        db.session.commit()
        return video, 201

    @marshal_with(resource_fields)
    def patch(self, video_id):
        args = video_update_args.parse_args()
        result = VideoModel.query.filter_by(id=video_id).first()
        if not result:
            abort(404, message="Video doesn't exist, cannot update")

        if args['name']:
            result.name = args['name']
        if args['views']:
            result.views = args['views']
        if args['likes']:
            result.likes = args['likes']

        db.session.commit()

        return result
```

And I'm trying to make so when I have an URL like http://127.0.0.1/5000/video/put/1/Test/80/2, I can use the funtion from the URL by typing it. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!